# Unable to update the dependencies of files that are encrypted by .Net Reactor

Tags: c#, encryption, dependencies, setup-project, net-reactor

I have a C#.Net Application, After building my C#.NET Output it is then encrypted using the 3rd-party .NET Reactor utility. While building Setup Development Project that Includes the encrypted file, VS2010 Says :

> "Unable to update the dependencies".

I've added dependencies manually and no thing changed, How can I ignore dependencies requirement for that file?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old post, but since I struggled with this for several hours in June 2017, I decided to post my solution in case it can help someone in the future. I'm using VS Community 2017 with .Net Reactor 5.0 to encrypt the exe output of a Windows Forms application, and I kept getting the following message on my Setup project (using VS Setup project... not Installshield):

```
"ERROR: Unable to update the dependencies of the project.  The dependencies for the object 'MyProgramNameHere.exe' cannot be determined."
```

After trying every setting in .Net Reactor, I determined that the culprit was the Anti ILDASM checkbox on the main tab (Files). Other features work fine, but the **Anti ILDASM will not work** with VS 2017 + VS Setup Project, so make sure that it is unchecked.

[image]

Comment: you lose an important feature tho, i'd rather change the setup builder, i've used setup2go in these situations, it won't complain about anything including mixing 32/64 bit files. it's old but works fine and simple to use.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with .Net Reactor 4.9.0.0 and a Visual Studio Setup Project in VS2010.  When I moved back to .Net Reactor 4.4.7.0 the Setup project (.vdproj) detected it's dependencies and worked.

I did not look further as I don't know what 4.9.0.0 offers me over 4.4.7.0 beyond several lost hours of research and hunting.